# Does I need to put meta tags in Search page of my E-commerce website?

Tags: seo, ecommerce, meta-tags

In my E-commerce website I got a product page.where I want to implement Meta-keywords,Meta-Description,etc.. I am a little confused about the task now.Is it necessary to do these things in search page? If yes what would be the best strategy to be used for this task?

Answer (score 2):

i think this might help you make a better decision about how to approach this http://youtu.be/HtSzi2MUegs, personally i always use a meta description by the way it goes in your head tag like this

```
<head>
<meta name="description" content="description for your page goes here" />
</head>
```

When think that i would recommend is make use of microformat also since you have an eCommerce site this will definitely help you

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170